# Color cells in WPF DataGrid dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, colors, cell

I populate the contents of a WPF DataGrid with dynamic data that is the result of a search. Now I would like to highlight those cells of the DataGrid, that contain data which was matched during the search.
Some hints about how this could be achieved are given [here](http://codefornothing.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/the-wpf-datagrid-and-me/). Is there more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding to the data is the best way. However if the data doesn't have the appropriate values then a converter needs to be employed (as in the examples).

if you want something more elegant, I'd add a conversion within the data and bind to that property instead

say like :

```
  public int RealProperty { .... }

  public SystemColors.AppWorkspaceColor Colour { return manglefromInt(RealProperty); }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a little more? I don't understand the Colour part of your example.